# Php и unixtime?

Tags: php

Пишу

```
 echo $unixtime = time("2015.2.2 8:00:00")*1000;
```

возвращает 1422866907000, а это Mon, 02 Feb 2015 08:46:50 GMT
В чем проблема?

Comment: 1422866907000 - время от 01.01.1970, формат timestamp

А дальше вы можете с ним манипулировать как хотите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     $unixtime = strtotime("2015-02-02 20:00:00")*1000;
```